# I am trying to give some text fields and drop down boxes some default values, which I will receive as an argument from other screen,

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I tried to transfer them into build context but the problem is that the values wont change.

Comment: You should declare you "ModalRoute.of(context)...." after "
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Here
....
}
"
otherwise you can't access

Comment: any recommendations or another way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to intialize the *agrs* inside the build method. Right now it's outside the build method because we are using context.

Like this(It's just a for demo where to intialize it.):-

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final Object args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments ?? "";
return Scaffold(
 ///////////
);
```

You have to initialize all textEditingController inside the build method as well.